# Is the order of iteration of KeyValuePair<> elements in a Dictionary<int,T>

Tags: c#, dictionary, iteration

I have a Dictionary with a few hundred thousand elements.  I need to perform a lengthy calculation on each pair in the dictionary, so for this purpose I'd like to spawn a few worker threads and assign each thread a range of elements in the dictionary to work on.

I understand that the "order is undefined" for hashtables and that's fine - all i care about is this:

if I do this from different threads:

```
int count = 0;
foreach (KeyValuePair<int, IDataPoint> pair in pointDictionary)
{
    if (count >= min && count <= max) // min,max different for each thread
    {
        // do stuff
    }
    ++count;
}
```

will the elements in pointDictionary be visited in the same order on different threads?

If not, I'll have to break up the dictionary into N dictionaries, and pass one of each of the mini-dictionaries to the N worker threads.

Comment: Just wondering: Wouldn't Parallel LINQ be an option? `from pair in pointDictionary.AsParallel() select ...`?

Comment: @Michael - yes, except this code is targeting .net 2.0 unfortunately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, as long as the dictionary has not been modified.

[Is the order of objects returned by FOREACH stable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/167096/is-the-order-of-objects-returned-by-foreach-stable)